# NServicebus configure ravendb port

Tags: nservicebus

I'm trying to change the default port that nservicebus uses for ravendb, what configuration setting do I add/change to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this link will help you out... [nservicebus-3-2-samples-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806242/nservicebus-3-2-samples-issue)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="NServiceBus.Persistence" connectionString="Url=http://localhost:8081;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Beauty! Thanks=) Knew it'd be simple, but I figured someone else will likely Google "Configure ravendb port for NServiceBus" as I did and not get an immediate response=)